# UITableView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the `UITableView`(**tableA**) with custom cells(**cellA**). Inside of each cell I have some views and `UITableView`(**tableB**) with Custom cells(**cellB**). There is a button in each **cellB**. I need to handle the `TouchUpInside` action from this buttons, but when user taps outside buttons I need to animate **cellA** selection and call method `-(void)didSelectRowAtIndexPath` from **tableA** delegate. In other words, user should select **cellA** then he taps outside button, **tableB** should miss this action for **tableA**. How can I do this?

I tried to set `userInteractionEnabled` property to `false` for **tableB** and **cellB**, but in this case buttons became disabled.

Comment: If **tableA** and **tableB** are real, where then is **tableC**? And more importantly, if **tableC** is real will its cells be named **cellC**. So confused right now...Am **I** real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the delegate of tableB, implement `didSelectRowForIndexPath` to make table A select the current row. The row will only receive the action if the touch wasn't on the button.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableA selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPathThatContainsTableB];
}
```

You may need to call the delegate method for tableA's delegate yourself.

Comment: Shame on me! This is so simple decision! Thank you very much, guy!